# How to make first text input become first responder and show keyboard with Eureka forms?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka forms swift library here: [Eureka forms](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)

I would like to have my first row of the input form become the first responder every time the view appears.  I tried adding a .cellUpdate callback which is fired everytime the view appears, and doing a cell.becomeFirstResponder() but this did not work.  Could someone with experience in this library please help?  Thanks.

Comment: what is the type of your cell? is a TextRow, ImageRow, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController3: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        form +++ Section("Custom cells")
            <<< TextRow("TextRow"){_ in
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let row = self.form.rowByTag("TextRow") as! TextRow
        row.cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Reinier!!!  I see that you are a contributor to Eureka.  Would greatly appreciate if you could take a look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662315/how-do-you-remove-the-next-previous-done-toolbar-in-eureka-forms

Comment: @demig0d I will see, and post my results, don't worry

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS 10 or with the newer Eureka. What does work is calling this in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: what if we have a PickerInputRow, which we want to make it as the firstResponder?

Comment: I will review that @Alexi as soon as I have something I will post it as update

Comment: hey @ReinierMelian, got the solution. The cell has a member named cellBecomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Nice man you got it, congratulations! I was lunching ;) best regards @Alexi

Answer (score 3):

Hook it in cellSetup, this way we don't need to lookup the cell in viewDidAppear

```
form +++ Section("")
        <<< TextRow() {
            $0.title = "Name"
            $0.value = list?.name ?? ""
            $0.cellSetup() { cell, row in
                  cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            $0.onChange() {
                self.list.name = $0.value ?? ""
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Reinier's answer, here is another way worked for me.

Directly call $0.cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder() in setting up the form.

```
        form +++ Section()
        <<< ZipCodeRow() {
            $0.value = postal_code
            $0.cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
```

Comment: This does not work on iOS 10 or with the newer Eureka.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

In ViewDidLoad() add:

```
let row = self.form.rowBy(tag: "TextRow.tag") as! TextRow
row.cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```