# How do you remove the < > (next / previous) Done toolbar in Eureka forms?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

How do I remove the toolbar with " < >    Done" on top of the keyboard when a Eureka form row is selected?  I'd just like to have the regular keyboard.  It isn't clear from the documentation how to do this.  Also, what is this toolbar generally referred to as in the iOS documentation?  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must override the following method on your `viewController`

```
override func inputAccessoryViewForRow(row: BaseRow) -> UIView?
```

and simply return nil there something like this

```
override func inputAccessoryViewForRow(row: BaseRow) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

### Swift 3.0

thanks to @ T.Coutlakis

```
override func inputAccessoryView(for row: BaseRow) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

this is the result

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: In Swift 3, the method is: `inputAccessoryView`